# A Differential Equation in Rindler Spacetime

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have derived the following differential equation, which determines the co-ordinates assigned to path of light in Rindler spacetime.

> $ \Big ( \frac{dx}{d \beta} \Big )^2 + \Big ( \frac{dy}{d \beta} \Big )^2 + \Big ( \frac{dz}{d \beta} \Big )^2 = (1 + cx)^2 $,

where $\beta$ is a parameter and $c$ is a constant.

I have no clue how to solve this differential equation. Any ideas?

Comment: There are too many unknowns.

Comment: Exactly my concern. I am working in a four dimension spacetime with a particular metric tensor. After calculating the infinitesimal metric, $ds^2$, and putting it to zero, I get this. What am I missing?

Comment: Other equations, probably.

Comment: All right, I got it. I wasn't looking at the 4 equations that describe the non-linear co-ordinate transformation in this case.